# Filter posts of custom post type by meta key in (List All Section)

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, admin, metabox

How can I filter the posts which are displayed on the admin list all page of a custom post based on the value of the a value.

So far I know how to do the following anywhere on the front end:

```
$args = array(
     'meta_key' => 'magic_key',
     'meta_value' => $post_id,
    'post_type' => 'question',
    'post_status' => 'publish',

);

$posts = get_posts($args);
```

How do i incorporate this into the List All page of this custom post type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the action `pre_get_posts` . Just make sure to check `is_post_type_archive('question')` and `is_admin()` to prevent affect queries in the whole website.